# Query error in MS Access 2007 when trying to connect to SQL Tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is my first post and hopefully I am asking the right question.

I am trying to pull data from a SQL server linked table into a ms access 2007 table using the following query

```
SELECT PTNT.PTNT_SEQ_NBR, PTNT.INTERFERON_RECEIVED_FROM_OTHER_SOURCE
INTO tblGetNonCMKfills.PTNT_SEQ_NBR, tblGetNonCMKfills.InterferonReceivedFromOtherSource
FROM PTNT
GROUP BY PTNT.PTNT_SEQ_NBR;
```

Although when I try to even save the query it gives me the error message

"Query input must contain at least one table or query"

Maybe I'm missing something obvious here, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your [`INTO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208934%28v=office.12%29.aspx) clause you just need to provide the name of the table you want to be created to insert the data into, not the column names.

```
SELECT PTNT.PTNT_SEQ_NBR, PTNT.INTERFERON_RECEIVED_FROM_OTHER_SOURCE
INTO tblGetNonCMKfills
FROM PTNT
ORDER BY PTNT.PTNT_SEQ_NBR;
```

Additionally you cannot use a `GROUP BY` clause in a query unless you are performaing some sort of aggregation in the `SELECT`. I am assuming what you really wanted here was an `ORDER BY` clause.